# Invalid postback or callback argument in ImageButton

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have an problem with my Click event to Button (Image Button) Delete.
I know that have other questions about this, but I don't understood nothing!

I didn't understand no answer! I did all that specifies in all other questions!
Other events in this page that make "Redirect" to example, works good!

I'm clear? Need more details? Stack trace or more code?

The error is:

> Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

My page:

```
<div id="Users" align="center">
        <asp:Button ID="btnCreate" class="btn" Font-Bold="true" runat="server" OnClick="btnCreate_OnClick" />
        <br />
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" GridLines="None"
            CssClass="table table-bordered table-striped" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="14px">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DisplayName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProfileName" />
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="btnEdit" ImageUrl="style/edit_16.png" runat="server" OnClick="btnEdit_OnClick" />
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDelete" ImageUrl="style/delete_16.png" runat="server" OnClick="btnDelete_OnClick" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
```

My event:

```
protected void btnDelete_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
    string UserName = row.Cells[0].Text;

    using (objConexao = new SqlConnection(strStringConexao))
    {
        using (objCommand = new SqlCommand(strDeleteUser, objConexao))
        {
            try
            {
                objConexao.Open();
                objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", UserName);
                var objDataReader = objCommand.ExecuteReader();
            }
            finally
            {
                objConexao.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Page_Load and CarregaGrid()

```
public void CarregaGrid()
{
    var listaRequest = new UsersNDR().ConsultUsers();
    if (listaRequest != null)
    {
        this.GridView1.DataSource = listaRequest;
        this.GridView1.DataBind();

        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            string idioma = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName.ToString();

            if (Session["idioma"].ToString() != null)
            {
                idioma = Session["idioma"].ToString();
            }

            ImageButton btnDelete = (ImageButton)row.FindControl("btnDelete");
            ImageButton btnEdit = (ImageButton)row.FindControl("btnEdit");
            btnDelete.ToolTip = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("btnDelete");
            btnEdit.ToolTip = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("btnEdit");
        }
    }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string idioma = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName.ToString();

    if (Session["idioma"].ToString() != null)
    {
        idioma = Session["idioma"].ToString();
    }

    Idioma.MudaCultura(idioma);
    btnCreate.Text = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("btnCreate");
    GridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("UserName");
    GridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("DisplayName");
    GridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("email");
    GridView1.Columns[3].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("ProfileName");
    GridView1.Columns[4].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("Action");
    CarregaGrid();
}
```

Comment: On a side note, you do not need the `try-finally` block that closes the connection, that is what the `using (objConexao = new SqlConnection(strStringConexao))` does automatically for you.

Comment: Can you post the code from your `Page_Load` event?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the fact that are re-binding the grid on every post back is the issue, try wrapping the grid altering logic in `!IsPostBack`, like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        string idioma = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName.ToString();

        if (Session["idioma"].ToString() != null)
        {
            idioma = Session["idioma"].ToString();
        }

        Idioma.MudaCultura(idioma);
        btnCreate.Text = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("btnCreate");
        GridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("UserName");
        GridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("DisplayName");
        GridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("email");
        GridView1.Columns[3].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("ProfileName");
        GridView1.Columns[4].HeaderText = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("Action");
        CarregaGrid();
    }
}
```